# How to sort hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have the following hash:

```
scores = {
  "Charlie" => 0
  "Delta" => 5 
  "Beta" => 2
  "Alpha" => 0
}
```

The numbers listed are integers, and the teams are represented as strings.

How can I sort the list by score, and if there is a tie, list it alphabetically, and then output it?

I imagine the intended output to look like:

```
1. Delta, 5 pts
2. Beta, 2 pts
3. Alpha, 0 pts
4. Charlie, 0 pts
```

I sorted the hash, but am not sure how to sort by alphabetical order if there is a tie. The code I used is below:

```
scores = Hash[ scores.sort_by { |team_name, scores_array| scores_array.sum.to_s } ]
```

Comment: http://www.rubyinside.com/how-to/ruby-sort-hash

Comment: I've found that link fairly useful, let alone from the fact that it doesn't really explain how to have it sort by a second key if there is a tie.Check out my edit.

Comment: There isn't a tie in your example data.

Comment: I edited my question to show an example of a tie @Stefan

Answer (score 4):

In Ruby, [`Array`s are lexicographically ordered](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E). You can make use of that fact for sorting by multiple keys: just create an array of the keys you want to sort by:

```
scores.sort_by {|team, score| [-score, team] }.to_h
#=> {'Delta' => 5, 'Beta' => 2, 'Alpha' => 0, 'Charlie' => 0}
```

Comment: _"Arrays are lexicographically ordered"_ – do you mean `String`s?

Comment: No, I mean `Array`s, otherwise my solution wouldn't work. This is actually documented in [`Array#<=>`'s RDocs](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) as well as [the RubySpec](https://github.com/ruby/spec/blob/master/core/array/comparison_spec.rb#L5-L16). This is also true of `String`s, although [badly documented](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) and [specified](https://github.com/ruby/spec/blob/master/core/string/comparison_spec.rb).

Comment: This is very clever!

Comment: @Schwern: It's actually a standard Ruby idiom, I was very surprised that it hadn't been mentioned before.

Answer (score 2):

The general pattern for sorting a Hash into a sorted Array of key/value pairs looks like this.

```
sorted_array_of_tuples = hash.sort { |a,b| ... }
```

A `Hash` has the [Enumerable mixin](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html) which means it can use [`sort`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort). Used on a Hash `sort` compares tuples (two element Arrays) of the key and value, so we can craft block that compares both the key and value easily.

Usually you then use the sorted Array.

```
sorted = hash.sort { ... }
sorted.each { |t|
    puts "#{t[0]}: #{t[1]}"
}
```

But you can turn it back into a Hash with [`to_h`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h). Since Hashes in Ruby remember the order their keys were inserted, the newly minted Hash created from the sorted Array will retain its sorting.

```
sorted_hash = hash.sort { |a,b| ... }.to_h
```

...but if more keys are added to `sorted_hash` they will not be sorted, they'll just go at the end. So you'll probably want to freeze the sorted hash to prevent modifications ruining the sorting.

```
sorted_hash.freeze
```

---

As for the sort block, in other languages an idiom of "compare by this, and if they're equal, compare by that" would look like this:

```
sorted_scores = scores.sort { |a,b|
    # Compare values or compare keys
    a[1] <=> b[1]    || a[0] <=> b[0]
}
```

This takes advantage that [`<=>`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) returns `0` when they're equal. In other languages `0` is `false` so you can use logical operators to create a whole chain of primary, secondary, and tertiary comparisons.

But in Ruby `0` isn't `false`. Only `false` is `false`. Usually this is a good thing, but here it means we need to be more specific.

```
sorted_scores = scores.sort { |a,b|
  # Compare values
  cmp = a[1] <=> b[1]
  # Compare keys if the values were equal
  cmp = a[0] <=> b[0] if cmp == 0
  # Return the comparison
  cmp
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use <=> to compare and do it in a block where you first compare by value (score) and if those match, then compare by key (name).

```
scores = {
  "Alpha" => 0,
  "Beta" => 2,
  "Charlie" => 0,
  "Delta" => 5,
}

# convert to an array of arrays
# => [[Alpha, 0], [Beta, 2], [Charlie, 0], [Delta, 5]]
# then sort by value and, if needed, by key
scores = scores.to_a.sort! { |a,b|
  cmp = a[1] <=> b[1]             # sort by value (index = 1)
  cmp = a[0] <=> b[0] if cmp == 0 # sort by key (index = 0) if values matched
  cmp
}.to_h # convert back to a hash

puts scores
```

Or if you want to extract the comparison code into a method for reuse/clarity, you can have it call the method.

```
# Compare entries from the scores hash.
# Each entry has a name (key) and score (value) (e.g. ["Alpha", 0].
# First compare by scores, then by names (if scores match).
def compare_score_entries(a, b)
  cmp = a[1] <=> b[1]
  cmp = a[0] <=> b[0] if cmp == 0
  return cmp
end

scores = scores.sort(&method(:compare_score_entries)).to_h
```

Comment: Good catch - I was thinking in JavaScript.  I changed it to `==`

Answer (score 0):

You can sort it like this

```
scores = {
  "Charlie" => 0,
  "Delta" => 5,
  "Beta" => 2,
  "Alpha" => 0
}
puts scores
  .map{|name, score| [-score, name]}
  .sort
  .zip((0...scores.size).to_a)
  .map{|(score, name), i| "#{i + 1}. #{name}, #{-score} pts"}
```

notice the minus score. It a trick to sort integer reversely.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
scores = {
  'Charlie' => 0,
  'Delta' => 5,
  'Beta' => 2,
  'Alpha' => 0
}

scores_sorted = scores.sort_by { |_key, value| -value }

scores_sorted.each.with_index(1) do |value, index|
 puts "#{index}. #{value[0]}, #{value[1]} pts"
end
```